# Is there any way to change the drawable image if the state is focused using android studio

Tags: android

I have research regarding on the state focused function of android java then I did apply this functionality on my project. However when I try to used this function it not work when I focused my cursor mouse on my image. I have module where I need to change the state images here is the example.

1. Default Color cloud is green
2. When the state pressed then the yellow cloud will do apply.
3. When the state focused then the orange cloud will do apply

The 1 and 2 List is now working well, the main problem here is the state focused it's not working well.

**Here is my Selector XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item  android:state_focused="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/orange_cloud"/>
    </item>

    <item  android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/yellow_cloud"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/green_cloud"/>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Main Activity XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Default Image:**

[image: Default Image]

Press State:

[image: State Press]

Focused State: Not working

Answer (score 0):

The reason is quite simple, `ImageView` or `Button` in Android generally do not show `state_focused` when touching the screen. Only when using a trackball or a remote, for example on Android TV. Think about `state_focused` as a mouse hover on desktop. There's really no way to mimic that with a touch.

On the other hand, you can focus an `EditText` for example.

Comment: Hi Vucko, Is this state focused working on real mobile device, because right now im just using the android emulator. I'am just thinking if the apk install on my mobile the state focused will work

Comment: No, it will not make a difference. With a touch, you cannot trigger that state on an ImageView or a button. You might be able to do it in code by doing `imageView.requestFocus` but I'm not sure you want that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add android:state_pressed="false" to focused item tag as below -

```
<item  android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/orange_cloud"/>
</item>
```

Also "state_focused" is whenever the view is focused on using a dpad or the trackball.
Views don't show a focused state on touch.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: You can not see the result on a device with touch. What are you using to see the result?

Comment: im using the android studio emulator for this.

Comment: even on the mobile device this function is not working